# Pandas how to separate elements in order to create columns in this log file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a log file with lines like this :

2022-10-20 14:23:06,709 [12] INFO XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX - XXXX XXXX, Added XXXX in XXXX for thread: XX, XXXX exists: XXX

I would like to create 6 columns, like this :

Column 1 : 2022-10-20

Column 2 : 14:23:06,709

Column 3 : [12]

Column 4 : INFO

Column 5 : XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX

Column 6 : XXXX XXXX, Added XXXX in XXXX for thread: XX, XXXX exists: XXX

but as you can see it's not possible by delimiting the elements with spaces. It creates 17 columns when I do it with spaces. Does anyone have any idea how to delimit the elements so that I can create the columns?

Thanks !

Comment: You can do direct indexing on the string if the format is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way about it
we need a rule to apply to the log file when reading here
we can split on spaces but only first 5 spaces

```
lines=[]

# open the log file
with open("csv2.txt") as fi:
    for line in fi:
        line = re.split(r"\s+", line, 5) # split only 5 times per line
        lines.append(line)         # build a list of list

df=pd.DataFrame(lines) # create dataframe
df
```

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   2022-10-20  14:23:06,709    [12]    INFO    XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX     - XXXX XXXX, Added XXXX in XXXX for thread: XX...
1   2022-10-21  14:23:06,709    [12]    INFO    XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX     - XXXX XXXX, Added XXXX in XXXX for thread: XX...
2   2022-10-21  14:23:06,709    [12]    INFO    XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX     - XXXX XXXX, Added XXXX in XXXX for thread: XX...
```